# Не получается обнаружить библиотеку assimp

Tags: c++, opengl, графика

Пытаюсь запустить готовый проект по этому мануалу: https://habr.com/ru/post/338998/; получаю ошибку  [image: assimp]. Версия библиотеки 3.3.1, компилировались как и в пособии с помощью CMake. Работаю в Visual Studio 2017. В дополнительных зависимостях указал полный путь до файла с именем. Возможно вопрос глупый, но все же.

Comment: Скопируйте указанную dll к exe файлу в ту же папку. При необходимости, повторить